# Dual element of supporting function

Tags: convex-analysis, riemannian-geometry, metric-geometry, finsler-geometry

Problem : $(\mathbb{R}^n,\|\ \|)$ has a smooth and strictly convex
norm. When $f(x)=\|x\|$, then find a directional derivative of a function $f$, i.e. $\frac{d}{dt}f(x+tv)$ for $\|x\|=1$.

**Refer :** [1] On intrinsic geometry of surface in normed spaces  - Burago and Ivanv

[2] Convex analysis - Rockafellar

Comment: It's not clear what the question is.

Answer (score 0):

When $S$ is $\|\ \|$-unit sphere, then $N(x),\ x\in S$ is
out unit normal vector. Then we have a supporting function $h_x$
s.t. $h_x(V)=\frac{\langle N,V\rangle}{\langle
N,x\rangle}$.

Hence we have $$\frac{d}{dt}f(x+tv) =h_x(v) $$